# How do I use the information from an option pane in an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, jframe, joptionpane

I'm trying to figure out how to assign a name/title to the options used in an option pane so that I can use them in an if-statement. Here's the code I have so far:

```
int i = 0;
while(i<1){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            String[] options = new String[2];
            options[0] = new String("Peat");
            options[1] = new String("Repeat");
            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame.getContentPane(),"Peat and Repeat were walking on a bridge\nPeat fell off, "
                    + "who was left?","", 0,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null,options,null);
    }
```

What would you recommend I do next to finish this "joke"?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean by your question is how do you determine what option was selected by the user? JOptionPane.showOptionDialog returns the index of the selected option. So you can do something like:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] options = {"Peat", "Repeat"};

        int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Peat and Repeat were walking on a bridge\nPeat fell off, who was left?","", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null,options,null);

        if(selectedOption == 0) System.out.println("Peat selected");
        else System.out.println("Repeat selected");
    }
}
```

When the user selects "Peat" it will print "Peat selected".

When they selected "Repeat" it will print "Repeat selected"